# argument of type char * parameter of type lpcwstr

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling

i getting error "argüment of type char * parameter of type lpcwstr" at c++ how is it repair ?

```
char text[MAX_PATH]= {};
sprintf(text, "Number of Words: %S", computerName);
sprintf(text, "Number of Sentences: %S", userName);
sprintf(text, "Number of Digits: %d", objSystemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors);
sprintf(text, "Number of Upper Case: %d", bit);
MessageBox(NULL, text , L"Sistem Bilgisi", MB_OK);
```

Comment: You're mixing narrow chars and wide strings. You need to use one or the other when feeding the arguments to MessageBox()

Comment: @AhmetKorkusuz Also note, each of your `sprintf()` calls doesn't add to `text`, but overwrites the current contents!

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox receives LPCWSTR, you can represent it as wchar_t instead of char and use wsprintf for write in wchar_t, like this:

```
wchar_t text[MAX_PATH]= {};
wsprintf(text, L"Number of Words: %s", computerName);
wsprintf(text, L"Number of Sentences: %s", userName);
wsprintf(text, L"Number of Digits: %d", objSystemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors);
wsprintf(text, L"Number of Upper Case: %d", bit);
MessageBox(NULL, text , L"Sistem Bilgisi", MB_OK);
```

Comment: Technically, `MessageBox()` receives `LPCTSTR`, which is either `LPCSTR` (`const char*`) or `LPCWSTR` (`const wchar_t*`) depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined. If you want to work with `wchar_t` directly, you need to call `MessageBoxW()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

note that LPCWSTR is defined in winnt header as :
`typedef const WCHAR* LPCWSTR` which means a pointer to const wide char.
In your case text is table of char. the second parameter for MessageBox had to be a LPCWSTR in case your project use UNICODE.
So if you try to change your declaration for `char text[MAX_PATH]= {};` by `wchar_t text[MAX_PATH]= {};` it would fix your compile problem.
However your MessageBox will display an empty text message as said in the comments sprintf will not add texts to you text variable.

Comment: The calls to `sprintf` will fail to compile if given wide strings.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: `sprintf()` accepts wide string input values when using the `%S` specifier (note the capital `S`).

Comment: @JonathanPotter: You would have to use a `char`-based buffer, yes.  But you can pass wide string input values and they will be converted to Ansi during the formatting of the buffer. That is what `%S` is for. Likewise for `swprintf()` - `%S` will accept a narrow string as input and convert it to wide during formatting of the `wchar_t` buffer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Surprisingly enough I know how to use wsprintf etc, my original comment was directed at the answerer in an attempt to help him improve his answer.

Comment: There are big differences between `wsprintf()` (Win32) and `s(w)printf()` (CRTL).  `wsprintf()` only supports a fraction of the options that `s(w)printf()` supports.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to call `MessageBoxA()` instead:

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, text, "Sistem Bilgisi", MB_OK);
```

Otherwise, if you continue calling the `TCHAR` version of `MessageBox()`, you need to update your code to use `TCHAR` for your text:

```
TCHAR text[MAX_PATH] = {};
_stprintf(text,
  _T("Computer Name: %ls\nUserName: %ls\nNumber of Processors: %u\nBit: %d"),
  computerName,
  userName,
  objSystemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors,
  bit
);
MessageBox(NULL, text, TEXT("Sistem Bilgisi"), MB_OK);
```

Otherwise, call the `WCHAR` version of `MessageBox()` and use `WCHAR` for your text:

```
WCHAR text[MAX_PATH] = {};
swprintf(text,
  L"Computer Name: %ls\nUserName: %ls\nNumber of Processors: %u\nBit: %d",
  computerName,
  userName,
  objSystemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors,
  bit
);
MessageBoxW(NULL, text, L"Sistem Bilgisi", MB_OK);
```